# How come I can't tail my log?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, logging

In my python script, I have this:

```
count = 0
while 1:
    print count
    count += 1
```

I saved this file and I ran it.

```
nohup python count.py >> test.log &

$tail -f test.log
```

Nothing shows up when I tail it.

Comment: I ran your script and did a tail... it works just fine. you have something else going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you redirect Python output, the `stdout` stream is opened in buffered mode (instead of line-buffered mode). This means that output is kept in memory until enough lines have been printed before flushing the buffer.

To see lines immediately, you need to flush the output stream:

```
import sys

count = 0
while 1:
    print count
    sys.stdout.flush()
    count += 1
```

Alternatively, use the `-u` command line switch to force unbuffered I/O:

```
nohup python -u count.py >> test.log &
```

or you can use the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 nohup python count.py >> test.log &
```

or re-open the `stdout` filehandle in unbuffered mode:

```
import os
import sys

sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

In Python 3.3 and up this is all a little simpler; you simply tell `print()` to flush:

```
print(count, flush=True)
```

Comment: There's probably a way to make the writes unbuffered also, but i don't know python.

Comment: But the script prints a high volume of information. The output buffer is being flushed frequently and it should tail just fine. Buffering is generally good for system performance - that's why its the default.

Comment: @tdelaney: Yup, I quite agree; that's why I presented the `.flush()` option first; you can control the frequency of flushes at least.

Answer (score 0):

It's because writes to standard output are buffered by default. You will see nothing until the buffer fills up or the file descriptor is flushed or closed.