# How to make nohup.out update with perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have a perl script that copies a large amount of files. It prints some text to standard out and also writes a logfile. However, when running with nohup, both of these display a blank file:

```
tail -f nohup.out 
tail -f logfile.log
```

The files don't update until the script is done running. Moreover, for some reason tailing the .log file does work if I don't use nohup!

I found a similar question for python (
[How come I can't tail my log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993397/how-come-i-cant-tail-my-log))

Is there a similar way to flush the output in perl?

I would use tmux or screen, but they don't exist on this server.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH),

```
HANDLE->autoflush( EXPR );
```

To disable buffering on standard output that would be,

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

Comment: Well, I feel silly that I missed that, thank you. I'm guessing there's no way to make a perl script flush its output while it's already running.